# Use return with nodejs to get back a value

Tags: node.js, callback

I am trying to set a variable using `var maxBatchId = findMaxBatchId()`, but (I guess because of callbacks) there is some issue with returning `maxBatchId` and I get "undefined" for the value of `maxBatchId`. I have tried returning `maxBatchId` in a number of places...this might be callback hell.

```
var finalMaxBatchId = findMaxBatchId() //NOT WORKING, is "undefined"

function findMaxBatchId() {
    pg.connect(conString,function(err,client,done) {
    console.log("Finding the maximum number in Batch Id...");
    client.query("SELECT MAX(batch_id) FROM urls;",function(err,result) {
      if (err) {
        cb(err, null);
        return;
      }
      maxBatchId = result.rows[0].max;
      client.end(); 
      return maxBatchId;
    });
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you are returning value from callback function which is called from somwhere else ( insert `console.trace()` before your return to get the picture - it's *not* part of the stack of findMaxBatchId call)

findMaxBatchId function itself does not have any parameters and does not return anything. Instead, pass your "continuation" callback as parameter and pass value to callback so you can use it:

```
function findMaxBatchId(cb) {
    pg.connect(conString,function(err,client,done) {
    console.log("Finding the maximum number in Batch Id...");
    client.query("SELECT MAX(batch_id) FROM urls;",function(err,result) {
      if (err) {
        cb(err);
        return;
      }
      maxBatchId = result.rows[0].max;
      client.end(); 
      cb(null, maxBatchId);
    });
  })
}

// later where you need max id, instead of "var finalMaxBatchId = findMaxBatchId()"
findMaxBatchId(function(err, finalMaxBatchId) {
   if (err) {
      // error!!!
      return;
   }
   // max batch id ready to be used
});
```

Comment: to clear out what is happening: pg callbacks are asynchronous (like most good node.js libs). it means that it will NOT be finished like in "normal" synchronous code. It will be finished "in some, undefined time", so to be sure, You have to call it like Andrey showed - after callback is REALLY called.